# Vlookup, Hlookup to find and concatenate values in matrix in google sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

**Problem:** 
Sheet 1 should return concatenated values to a certain index that is also hold in sheet 1.
Sheet 2 should be searched for this value.

**In my case:** Sheet 1 holds a string (e.g. "Demos - Sales Gespräche mit Leads") in column B. Now I would like to look for this value in a matrix in Sheet 2 and give back all column headers of the columns that hold this value ("Demos - Sales Gespräche mit Leads").
In my example there would be a couple of names of the person who is assigned to the certain job.

Here is an **example sheet:** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q3CrdNbWyVwUAnODwBA7G05FSPLThBHHlWMItt6PNDc/edit?usp=sharing

**Possible solution:** Some combination of concatenate, vlookup, index and hlookup. I just can't think of how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paste where you need and drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
 IF('Sheet 2'!$A$2:$Z=B2, 'Sheet 2'!$A$1:$Z$1, ))))
```

[image: 0]